# Data saving and data reading ( C Programming )

Tags: c

The code below will ask for input, and is supposed to print it after. 
However, I've encountered several problems.

---

**Problems**

- program stops working after I confirm the entry.
- when it is supposed to print the input, it instead prints out weird symbols.

---

**Questions**:

- How do I print the whole value of the variable?
  **For ex** :- When I input " *John Lemon* " for when it asks for " *Name:* ". 
  I would be able to print " *John Lemon* " instead of " *John* ".
- After printing the first value of the variable, how do I continue to print the second value and the third value of the variable wholly?
  **For ex** :
  ***Sample Output***
   Name: John Lemon
  Age: 21
  Address: 41, 2/2 Apple Street

---

What can I do to rectify this problem?

If possible, please explain in  layman terms as I'm new to C programming.
Sorry if this looks messy. I've tried my best to keep it as simple as possible.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char fname[]={"guest.dat"};

struct text
{
    char name;
    int age;
    char address;

};

void printing ()
{
    struct text t1;

    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen(fname,"r");

    printf("\nName: %c",t1.name);
    printf("\nAge: %d",t1.age);
    printf("\nAddress: %s",t1.address);
}

int main ()
{
    FILE *fp;

    int choice;

    struct text t1;

    fp=fopen(fname,"a+");

    fread(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,fp);

    printf("\nPlease enter name: ");
    scanf("%c",&t1.name);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\nPlease enter age: ");
    scanf("%d",&t1.age);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\nPlease enter address: ");
    scanf("%s",&t1.address);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\nConfirm? (Y/N): ");
    scanf("%c",&choice);

    if ( choice == 'y' | choice == 'Y')
    {
        fp=fopen(fname,"a+");
        fwrite(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,fp);
        fclose(fp);
        fflush(stdin);
        system("cls");
        printing();
    }
    else if ( choice == 'n' | choice == 'N')
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        system("cls");
        printing();
    }
    else
        fflush(stdin);
        system("cls");
        printf("Please try again!");
        system("pause");
}
```

Comment: For some reason beginner tutorials always start off with examples requiring interactive dialogues with the user via scanf. scanf is a bit tricky to use and it's not immediately obviously why it is tricky.

Comment: "char" type in C is a single character, before finishing this code, you should take a look of how char array works / pointers, and what does "&" in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program prints "weird symbols" because `t1` is never initialized in the `printing` function.

Here you never read from file:

```
void printing ()
{
    struct text t1;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(fname,"r");

    // Missing read from file

    printf("\nName: %c",t1.name);
    printf("\nAge: %d",t1.age);
    printf("\nAddress: %s",t1.address);
}
```

Further, this line:

```
printf("\nAddress: %s",t1.address);
```

is wrong. You use `%s` which is for `char*` but `address` is a `char`. So you must use `%c`. The same applies for the `scanf` of `address`.

Maybe you really wanted `struct text` to hold strings!? If so you should have used a `char array`. Currently the struct can only hold char (i.e. a single letter for name and address). Maybe you really wanted to do:

```
struct text
{
    char name[100];
    int age;
    char address[100];

};
```

and then use `%s` instead of `%c` for both `printf` and `scanf`.

Also here you have some "strange" code:

```
int main ()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int choice;
    struct text t1;

    // Why do you have the next to lines? Seems to be a mistake - remove them
    fp=fopen(fname,"a+");
    fread(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,fp);
```

Besides that, your code lacks all kind of checks of return values. Always check the value returned by `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite` and `scanf`.

Comment: so `scanf("%c",&t1.name)` will assign the input from name to `t1.name` and `scanf("%d",&t1.age)` will assign the input from age to `t1.age`?

Comment: @sugar - yes, but notice that `%c` is a char so name is just a single letter

Comment: to read a word from my input, i use `%s` even though my value is saved as `%c`?

Comment: @sugar - well.... To read a "word" (aka string) you use `%s` but **first** you must make sure that the variable used can hold a string! Do **not** use `%s` when the variable is a `char`type. You probably want to change your struct. Like `char name[100];` instead of `char name;`. After doing that you can use `%s`